# Setting fontsize for dirtree globally

Tags: fontsize, dirtree

I am using the `\dirtree` package to present some directories in my document. Is there a way to globally set size of `\dirtree` contents to someting other than what the document is set to? I can change the size for each directory tree separately by using something like:

```
\begin{tiny}
\dirtree{%
    .1 dir1.
    .1 dir2.
    .2 dir3.
}
\end{tiny}
```

Is there a way to define this is the preamble?

Only other option that I can see is to create a Macro in TeXstudio.

Comment: `\newcommand\mydirtree[1]{{\tiny\dirtree{#1}\par}}` then use `\mydirtree` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This works. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define

```
\newcommand\mydirtree[1]{{\tiny\dirtree{#1}\par}}
```

then use `\mydirtree{.....}`